# How to sync up different timelines and real events in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, time-dilation

###### Imagine this scenario:

1. Mike lives on a massive planet, so massive he experiences time going slowly.
2. Le petit prince lives on a small planet ( not much time dilation )
3. After millions of years (making a significant time gap between the two frames of reference), the little prince sees a supernova, but it is going to happen for Mike in a hundred years ( because his time is much behind after millions of years experiencing time dilation )
4. They both fly to meet somewhere in space to check on the area where prince saw the supernova;

###### What do they see?! who's timeline is real? How the reality changes for Mike?!

> Note: the travel time, acceleration, and speed are nothing especial and will not have a dramatic effect on the time experienced. not enough fast-forwarding for Mike during his travel to compensate for the time difference.

> Edit: Obviously this is not a homework question! it was a genuine question I couldn't solve originally so I asked for help. After digging more into it I realized the answer

Comment: There is no paradox? Mike and prince will just disagree how long ago the event happened, but will otherwise interact happily and similarly at where they meet.

Comment: There are no timelines in relativity, only [worldlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line). Point 3 assumes that there is always an underlying natural (absolute) synchronisation between Mike and the prince. Hence the idea of a growing 'time gap' between them, that makes Mike 'behind' the prince. But there is no such absolute notion of simulaneity in relativity (be it special or general). The only natural, non-relative way to synchronize both people is to have them meet - BTW point 4 does not explain how they can even meet at all if Mike is supposedly 'behind' the prince.

Comment: I figured it out, the important thing that I was missing was that the time stretches for Mike but would still map to the same time-frame as the prince as far as the events go. so during living on his massive planet, Mike would see the universe going a bit faster than Princes, hence still keeping in-sync as far as the outside events go.. Only events local to him go with a normal rate ( which would look slow motion to a prince peeking through a telescope ).
Please feel free to write an answer or lmk and I'll answer myself! Thanks :)

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin they could still meet, only Prince will have aged a lot more than Mike.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, I realized my mistake, I was looking at it the wrong way, there is only one scenario where synchronicity can be a problem and that's when the light path is affected, in which case fast-forwarding and slow-motion would happen as soon as we travel away and towards the massive object ( not applicable in this case ), also read my comment above ( They are not going to be out of sync as far as the non-local events are concerned )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The important thing that I was missing was that the time stretches for Mike but would still map to the same time-frame as the prince as far as the events go. So during living on his massive planet, Mike would see the universe going a bit faster than Princes, hence still keeping in sync as far as the outside events go while experiencing less local time.. Only events local to him go with a normal rate ( which would look slow motion to a prince, peeking through a telescope )

So 2000 years for the little prince could look like 1500 years for Mike but they would see everything the other one did, just at a different speed.

I was looking at it the wrong way, there is only one scenario where synchronicity can be a problem, and that's when the light path is affected, like in a black hole where light can not escape, in which case fast-forwarding and slow-motion would happen as soon as we travel away and towards the massive object ( not really measurable in this case ).